Change behaviour of Toggle Header Code File (Ctrl+k, Ctrl+o) in MSVS to include inline files (.inl) as well as source and header files (.cpp, .h)
In Visual Studio 2022 when working with a C++ project, Ctrl+k,Ctrl+o will swap between the corresponding header and source files, the command is called EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleHeaderCodeFile. If you're working in my_file.cpp, press Ctrl+k,Ctrl+o and  Visual Studio 2022 will take you to my_file.h and visa-versa.
Would it be possible to modify the behaviour of that command to include .inl files for templates (or .tpp) so that Ctrl+k,Ctrl+o would cycle between the three files my_file.cpp, my_file.h, my_file.inl (or my_file.tpp)
Does the functionality already exist (to cycle between the 3 file types) or if not how would I go about implementing such a functionality ?
(These old questions are asking about how to switch between .cpp and .h which is already known.
I also tried Stack Overflow searching this question "[visual-studio] switch between user defined file extensions", which is a slightly different question, but to cover a wider search, which returned 1 unrelated post.)

This is not about the keybinding, but the command it calls. If someone knows a plugin or how to change the behaviour/edit the command EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleHeaderCodeFile that would be a solution

Hi I've updated the answer as this feature is not officially supported by Visual Studio.

You can change keyboard shortcut behavior in the Tools > Options. Expand environment tab and select keyboard.You will be able to modify keyboard shortcuts to any available commands in VS.
However to cycle through customized file extensions, I suggest you to submit a feature request here to add a keyboard shortcut to toggle through code and template files.

And there's no way to write a plugin oneself? I have had a bit of a look around, but because I'm a noob in this particular area (MSVS plugin writing), some kind of start (eg a link) would be useful, from wiser folks. Or is it just too much effort. At some point it's just easier to find the relevant file and open it, than spending 2 weeks learning a new interface/API and language to write a plugin?

You may start with these official examples.The link gives a good start to create your own vsix extensions which allows creating customized commands with keybind.
Another example you could refer to is c# - VSIX window - key shortcut to execute ICommand - Stack Overflow.It created a customized save command.Hope these example could help you.
